# Linear (in)dependence of roots over the nonzero rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, radicals, rational-numbers

I was reading some question on this site and stream of thought led me to the creation of another question that could be trivial for someone but I am unable even to start solving it. I wanna share this question with you in hope that someone will be able to answer it.

Let $S_2$ be the set of square roots of all positive integers that are not of the form $a^2$ , $S_3$ the set of cube roots of all positive integers that are not of the form $a^3$, $...$ , $S_n$ the set of $n$-th roots of all positive integers that are not of the form $a^n$...

Now let us define set $S$ as $S=\bigcup_{n=2}^\infty S_n$.

The question is:

Does there exist a natural number $k$ and rational numbers $r_1,r_2,...,r_k$ (all different from zero) such that for some $k$ different elements of the set $S$, denote them as $s_1,s_2,...,s_k$, which are not in the same set of roots, for instance if $s_i$ is in the $S_4$ then $s_j$ is in the $S=(\bigcup_{n=2}^\infty S_n) \setminus S_4$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^{k}r_is_i=0$?

(All roots in this question are unique real roots.)

Comment: You are asking for something much stronger than a linear dependence relation (which certainly exists) if by "some $k$ elements" of the set $S$ you require the first $k$ elements.  However the weaker version is almost trivial, since $2\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{12} = 0$.

Comment: @hardmath There is additional assumption now, that those roots are in different constituent sets of the set $S$, that is more interesting version, to avoid trivialities as in your example.

Comment: So now all $k$ roots must be of a different exponent.

Comment: That refinement does not really avoid the near-trivialities, since $\sqrt{3} = \sqrt[4]{9}$.

Comment: @hardmath Those are not different elements of the set $S$, they are in different constituent sets but they do not satisfy requirement that they are different elements of $S$ so that is not valid counterexample.

Comment: What I'm saying is that $2\sqrt[4]{9} - \sqrt{12} = 0$ is still a dependence relation, conforming to your new requirement that the roots belong to different "index" constituent sets, $S_4$ and $S_2$ in this case.

Comment: @hardmath I would like that you post equation $2\sqrt[4]{9} - \sqrt{12} = 0$ as an answer, I will accept it, if answers are allowed to be so short.

Comment: Not equation, that is identity.

Comment: How about modifying the question so the answer is affirmative and non-trivial.

Comment: @orangeskid I was writing a comment to hardmath of the type "may I edit the question so many times until you no more have counterexamples" but did not add it, I think that I can do it with just one more edit, haha! If he wants I will do it.

Comment: @Ante P.: Yeah, you can do this: fix an order $N$ for the roots. Now consider distinct natural numbers that are ($N$-th power )-free. Their $N$-th roots will be linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. True, and takes some care to prove. It's a good start for a more general result.

Comment: @orangeskid Interesting, I actually had in mind a version that has roots of every order but is also (at least it looks to me) non-trivial.

Comment: @Ante P. : I would prove first for $N=2$, square roots. Even this one is interesting already. In the end, this statement with general $N$ might probably imply any valid one for different orders, since you can bring them to a common order.

Comment: @orangeskid [Look](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332093/another-independence-over-the-nonzero-rationals-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can devise examples, for arbitrarily large $k$, where the roots $s_i$ are drawn from different constituent classes, so that $\sum_{i=1}^k r_i s_i = 0$ with all coefficients $r_i$ nonzero integers.

A simple example with just two terms is $2\sqrt[4]{9} - \sqrt{12} = 0$.

Comment: [Is this also trivial?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332093/another-independence-over-the-nonzero-rationals-question)

Comment: No, it is not trivial as the Comment linking to an earlier Answer about just square roots of primes demonstrates.